# Hide one element while another is showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a way to hide one element (`.close-button`) while another (`#loading-animation`) is showing. How can I use conditionals in jQuery to achieve this?

Something like:

```
while ($('#loading-animation').show(100);) {
    $('.close-button').hide();
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but how can I format it correctly?

Comment: your animation, is it done with css or js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the complete callback of `show( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

```
 $('.close-button').hide();
 $('#loading-animation').show(100, function(){
       $('.close-button').show();
 });
```

All jQuery animations have a complete callback option

Reference: **[show() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**

Answer (score 1):

if your animation is performed with CSS (eg, css transitions)

then you can monitor the transition end event with this:

```
$('.close-button').hide();
$("#loading-animation").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(event){ 
    //this will run when the css transitions on your #loading-animation end
    $('.close-button').show();
}).show();
```

or you can perform the animation using jQuery animate:

```
$('.close-button').hide();
$("#loading-animation").animate({
    //do your transitions here
    //"left":"+=200"
}).promise().done(function(){
    //this will run when animate is done
    $('.close-button').show();
});
```